# Pandas - Reading multiple excel files into a single pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read multiple excel files into a Pandas Dataframe.

I have got the below code in place:

```
allFiles = glob.glob(base2 + "/*.xls"). <<-- Reading from path where all files are stored
list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(open(file_, 'rb').read()), sheet_name='Sheet1') <<-- using io module to read the file as there are some issue with the text format
    list_.append(df)

print(list_)
file = pd.DataFrame(list_)
```

When I open the Dataframe csv file, I see entire contents of a single file all in a single row. I am trying to have each row from the source file said in a separate row in the file output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than create the `pd.DataFrame` based on the list, use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to concatenate them, i.e.

```
file = pd.concat(list_)
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you found the answer helpful, you can [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).